# Windows 7 Ultimate Product key doesn't work without SP1?

Tags: windows-7, windows

HEy I tried my windows 7 ultimate sp1 key but is it normal that this key doesn't work with windows 7 ultimate? (No SP1 installed)
checking it on: http://d-fault.nl/PidCheck.aspx
Gives me the following results:

```
Validity     : Valid
Edition Type     : Ultimate
Description  : Windows 7 SP1 Ultimate Retail
Edition ID   : X16-95496
Key Type     : Retail
```

So does this SP1 actually matter?
Just wondering (Downloading SP1 right now)

Comment: Yes; it normal.  Why are you using a third party website that does god knows what to check your license key?

Answer (score 3):

From Microsoft's [own help topic on the issue](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/windows-7-activation-error-invalid-product-key):

> You can't use a product key for Windows 7 with Service Pack 1 (SP1) to activate a copy of Windows 7 without SP1.

You can leave the key blank on install, and follow [this helpful guide](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/activate-windows#1TC=windows-7) to activating Windows 7 after SP1 is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I remember some XP SP3 serial numbers not working on XP SP2 and below,
so I think you might be right, the same could apply to Windows 7.

Also, where exactly is windows not accepting the serial number, during the setup phase,
or inside windows itself, are you connected to the internet when it tries to activate online?